# Passing directory paths as strings to argparse in Python

Tags: python, cmd, program-entry-point, argparse

**Scenario:** I have a python script that receives as inputs 2 directory paths (input and output folders) and a variable ID. With these, it performs a data gathering procedure from xlsx and xlsm macros, modifies the data and saves to a csv (from the input folder, the inner functions of the code will run loops, to get multiple files and process them, one at a time).

**Issue:** Since the code was working fine when I was running it from the Spyder console, I decided to step it up and learn about cmd caller, argparse and the **main** function. I trying to implement that, but I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized arguments (the output path I pass from cmd)
```

**Question:** Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

**Obs:** If the full script is required, I can post it here, but since it works when run from Spyder, I believe the error is in my argparse function.

**Code (argparse function and __main__):**

```
# This is a function to parse arguments:
def parserfunc():
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process Files')
    parser.add_argument('strings', nargs=3)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    arguments = args.strings
    return arguments

# This is the main caller    
def main():
    arguments = parserfunc()
    # this next function is where I do the processing for the files, based on the paths and id provided):
    modifierfunc(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])

#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In your case you can simply use `sys.argv` global array without any parsing

Comment: @grapes indeed, with sys.argv (now that I know it exists) this becomes quite trivial, thanks for sharing the information. Still, I would like to know what I am doing wrong with the argparse, so I can learn how to use it properly.

Comment: Does your outputpath contain spaces? If yes the two parts could have counted as separate arguments and you would have passed four (or more) instead of three arguments. In that case you should properly quote or escape your input. Your parsing function works for me.

Comment: @Graipher is there a way to change the delimiter between arguments?

Comment: Not that I know of. But just call it with `script.py "input/file/Document with spaces.txt" output/file/Also\ with\ spaces.txt id` So either surround your arguments with quotes or escape the spaces with a backslash.

Comment: @Graipher thanks, that is really helpfull.

Comment: When debugging `argparse` code it is useful to display `sys.argv[1:]` and `args` (or all of the argparse error message).  In this case `sys.argv[1:]` should have 3 strings.  If not, there's a problem with the input - possibly with how the shell splits the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decided to use `argparse`, then make use of named arguments, not indexed. Following is an example code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input')
parser.add_argument('output')
parser.add_argument('id')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.input, args.output, args.id) # this is how you use them
```

In case you miss one of them on program launch, you will get human readable error message  like

> error: the following arguments are required: id

Answer (score 1):

You could drop the entire parserfunc() function. 
`sys.argv` does indeed contain all arguments (always processed as a string) as mentioned by grapes.

So instead of this:

```
modifierfunc(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])
```

This should suffice:

```
import sys
modifierfunc(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Perhaps, first do a print, to see if the sys.argv holds the values you expect.

```
print('Argument 0='+sys.argv[0])
print('Argument 1='+sys.argv[1])
print('Argument 2='+sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @grapes, when printing data ... calling everything "Argument 0" does indeed, not make sense  ;=D

Comment: That wasn't an important edit, I know, but it happened to me to get downvoted for a simple typo in an example, so i fixed it)

Comment: It was not meant as sarcasm @grapes. If you received down-votes for something that small, those people were probably in a bad mood.. You're trying to help, typos happen to everyone.